# RHive package in R and rhive.connect() Error ClassNotFoundException

Tags: r, hive, cloudera-cdh, rstudio-server

I, we configure all (apparently) correct and we receive the next error when run

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(RHIVE_HIVESERVER_VERSION="2");
library("rJava", lib.loc="/usr/lib64/R/library")
library("RJDBC", lib.loc="/usr/lib64/R/library")
library("rhdfs", lib.loc="/usr/lib64/R/library")
hdfs.init()
library("Rserve", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
library("RHive", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
rhive.init()

rhive.connect(host="oururl",port="ourport", defaultFS="hdfs://ourhdfsservice", hiveServer2=TRUE ,updateJar=FALSE)
```

(I want to say `HIVE_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME` are correctly defined)

The error we receive:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.connect(HiveJdbcClient.java:337)
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.run(HiveJdbcClient.java:322)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:41)
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.connect(HiveJdbcClient.java:330)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at RJavaClassLoader.findClass(RJavaClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:38)
    ... 2 more
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to hiveserver
```

What happens here? We try to reinstall Hive but same error.

Answer (score 1):

Doble-check of `HIVE_HOME` for see if has correct configuration, `HIVE_HOME` libs, and revision of RHDFS and RJava packages.

Finally solved.

We need has a lot of care with this package because java dependencies are hard.